# check the values of the arraylist values in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to write a method that checks weather all the `Objects` in an `ArrayList` have the same value. For example, in the following code `list1` should return `true`, and `list2` should return `false`...

```
list1=[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
list2=[1,3,4,2,4,1,3,4,5,6,2,1,5,2,4,1]
```

What is the best way to write this method? Is there any quick methods to do this, or do I need to manually loop through the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you need to check if all the values in a list are the same?

```
boolean checkList(List<Integer> list) {
  if (list.isEmpty())
    return false;

  int value = list.get(0);
  for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    if (list.get(i) != value)
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

but I'd be careful about `null` values in the list, too...

Comment: You should start your for at 0. It's not an useful check but it's better than returning false if there is only one value in the `List`

Comment: If there is only one element in the list, the `for` block is not executed and `true` is returned.

Comment: The `i < list.size()` condition will not let it run (`1 < 1` is false). Anyway, you can try it out in your IDE.

Comment: Glad I still remember some Java :)